# Can't catch connection error clickhouse-driver db api

Tags: python, clickhouse, python-db-api

I'm trying to catch a connection error when connecting to kx using the clickhouse-driver db api in python. But for some reason, the try: block passes without errors, and I don't get exception

```
def __enter__(self):
try:
        self.connector = db.connect(dsn=self.connection_string)
    except Error as e:  # pass
        self.error = str(e)[:250]
        self.connector = None
    return self
```

And the error only happens when `execute` sql is executed. Is there any way to get a connection error at the moment of connection?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but you can add an issue to the clickhouse-driver project.  You could also take a look at the alpha level clickhouse-connect driver officially supported by ClickHouse Inc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `execute('select 1')`. Because only after execute we are creating instance of class, so after that I can get connection exception.

```
def __enter__(self):
    try:
        self.connector = dbp.connect(dsn=self.connection_string)
        self.cur = self.connector.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('select 1')
    except dbp.Error as e:
        self.error = '\nConnection error occurred: ' + '\n' + str(e)[:250]
        self.connector = None
    return self
```